# Validating ASP.NET MVC 3 controller's action params when using Dynamic Expressions API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic-linq

I have a standard ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller with an action that has following signature:
`public ActionResult Index(int? page, string sort, string sortDir)`
My view is using WebGrid so parameters are produced by it automatically.

Next I use Dynamic Expressions API (aka Dynamic LINQ) to convert parameters into query. Example:

```
var customerSummary = CustomerManager.CustomerRepository.GetQuery()
      .OrderBy(sort + " " + sortDir)
      .Select(c => new CustomerSummaryViewModel()
                  {
                      Id = c.Id,
                      Name = c.Name,
                      IsActive = c.IsActive,
                      OrderCount = c.Orders.Count
                  })
      .Skip(page.Value - 1 * 10) //10 is page size
      .Take(10)
      .ToList();
```

## The Goal

What I would like to do is to use [Dynamic Expressions API](http://nuget.org/packages/DynamicQuery) itself to validate parameters for sorting (and perhaps create a valid lambda). For example, I'd like to use `DynamicExpression.Parse()` or `DynamicExpression.ParseLambda()` methods to see if they produce `ParseException`, in which case I can replace erroneous params with default (e.g. sort by name ascending "Name ASC")...

## The Problem

The problem is that `IQueryable` extensions take only a string
If I wanted to use `ParseLambda` and then feed it to `.OrderBy` I cannot use direction (it takes in only property name). For example, I can do this:

```
var se = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<Customer, string>("Name"); // now I can use  .OrderBy(se) which is same as .OrderBy(c=>c.Name)
```

but not this

```
var se = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<Customer, string>("Name DESC");
```

## Recap

I would like to use Dynamic LINQ to 1) validate and 2) build predicates (for sorting) based on action parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Dymaic LINQ but you can do the following:

```
var customerSummary = CustomerManager.CustomerRepository.GetQuery();

if ("desc".Equals(sortDir, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
   customerSummary = customerSummary.OrderByDescending(sort);
else
   customerSummary = customerSummary.OrderBy(sort);

var pageNumber = page.GetValueOrDefault();
if (pageNumber < 1)
   pageNumber = 1;

customerSummary = customerSummary
   .Select(c => new CustomerSummaryViewModel()
      {
         Id = c.Id,
         Name = c.Name,
         IsActive = c.IsActive,
         OrderCount = c.Orders.Count
      })
   .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * 10) 
   .Take(10)
   .ToList();
```

I done something similar (except i used raw Expressions) in my project but gone even further.

I've created a base ViewModel like this:

```
class TableViewModel 
{
   public string SortColumn { get; set; }
   public bool IsAsc { get; set; }
   public int? PageNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And created a helper method that do all the paging/sorting work. Signature is like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> TableHelper(this IQueryable<T> source, TableViewModel model) { ... }
```

And when i need to receive data from my table control and return a requested piece of data, controller action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(TableViewModel model)
{
   var data = _productRepository.AsQueryable().TableHelper(model);

   ... //Operation on data
}
```

Common thing that before and after call of the helper you are free to apply any filtering or smth.

It's very convinient.

When i need to extend my ViewModel, i inherit it and add new members to child model.

**UPD:** If you decide to stay DLINQ, try the following signature - `OrderBy("Name", "ascending");`

**UPD2:** If you want to validate your sort parameter, i think, reflection is the only choise. Something like this:

```
bool doSort = typeof(Product).GetProperty(sort, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy /*Or whatever flags you need*/) != null
```

Going this way, you should apply a `OrderBy`/`OrderByDescending` logic only if `doSort` is true. Otherwise, just skip sorting or apply any default logic.

In my oppinion, the more functionality you want from your code, the less DLINQ seems to be suitable for it. Once `PropertyInfo` is obtained the next reasonable step could be to use it in expression. Once we do it, where would be a place for DLINQ? :)

I agree that the expression and reflection code is very ugly in actions, but moving it outside, for example, to ExtensionMethod, as in my case, or in NonAction mehod of a controller base class, saves your eyes from seeing it:)

Comment: I'd like to use Dynamic LINQ (as pew question). But besides that how do you validate "sort" param in your example? How do you make sure that "sort" is a valid property on your underlaying model? :)

Comment: I have updated the answer (see UPD2). For ordering with DLINQ, haven't you seen my first UPD? Does it work for you?

Comment: BTW, what would DLINQ do if you pass a wrong field name? Will it throw an exception?

Comment: Yes Dynamic LINQ has Parse methods that throw ParseException if expression is bad. Your approach using reflection works and I had it working as such before, but my question is *how* to do it with Dynamic LINQ...